# Add row in Pandas DataFrame at beginning of series (starting equity)

Tags: python, pandas

How can I add a row at the beginning in my Pandas DataFrame (df1) for the starting equity at Month 0?  As you can see below the monthly_ret doesn't start until Month 2 because there is no starting equity.  The starting equity = 300.38

```
Date            Month     Equity     monthly_ret    
1454025600000   1         317.9      
1456704000000   2         368.84     0.1602390689
1459382400000   3         338.19    -0.0830983624
1461888000000   4         348.16     0.0294804696
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `concat` method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat? You'd just create a DataFrame with a single row and then concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Create a one row data frame with the data for month 0, then use the appropriate [merging function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) -- concat would work the best probably.